# Erased .zshenv file by mistake

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, zshrc

I have erased/cleared my .zshenv file by running command `echo > .zshenv` unfortunately. I am not a pro in terminal and commands. Can I get back my old `.zshenv` file by any commands?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on macOS, you can get it back through Time Machine: https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh11422/11.0/mac/11.0

In future, you might also want to add

```
setopt NO_CLOBBER
```

to your `.zshrc` file. This prevents `>` from overwriting existing files. With `NO_CLOBBER` set, only `>|` or `>!` can overwrite existing files.

Additionally, you might want to get into the habit of using `>>` instead of `>`. `>>` can create new files, just like `>`, but unlike `>`, if the file already exists, instead of overwriting it, `>>` will simply append text to the file.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh11422/11.0/mac/11.0  This has helped me in restoring to older state of my file. Thanks @marlon richert

Comment: You're welcome. :) And thanks for the link! I added it to my answer.

Comment: @CholanMadala I added some more tips to my answer. Have a look.